# how to insert values in particular table based on user decisions

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on a small project where I need to insert the value into different tables based on the Slave Id, 
for example, if the user is sending multiple values with slave id 1 I need to insert the value in the table "Instant_Values_S1" and if the slave id 2 I need to insert the value into "Instant_Values_S2"
this is my code:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Instant_Values_S1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                          (
                              1,
                              utctime,
                              data[0],
                              data[1],
                              data[2],
                              data[3],
                              data[4],
                              data[5],
                              data[6],
                              data[7],
                              data[8],
                              data[9],
                              data[10],
                              data[11],
                              data[12],
                              data[13],
                              data[14],

                          ))
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
```

here I define the table name again and again but instead, I wanna give those automatically? can someone help me out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is a know limitation of SQL: you can use parameters for values, but not for table or columns names. But a SQL command is just a string and you can use Python to build the static part of the request. More or less:

```
table_names = [None, "Instant_Values_S1", "Instant_Values_S2" ]
# will raise exception if slave_id is not 1 or 2
req = "INSERT INTO " + table_names[slave_id] + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
c.execute(req, (slave_id, ...)
```